# .NET Core with Interop for Excel - xlTreemap gives Out of Range exception

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I've written a .NET Core WinForms application which writes to Excel. I can create many different types of charts but not a Treemap or Sunburst chart. I get the following error:

> Value does not fall within the expected range

On the final line of this code:

```
        var charts = currentWorkSheet.ChartObjects() as ChartObjects;
        var chartObject = charts.Add(1, 1, 1100, 500);
        var chart = chartObject.Chart;
        chart.ChartType = XlChartType.xlTreemap;
```

I'm using the Nuget package: Microsoft.Office.Core 15.0.0. Any idea how I can get this working?

Comment: "the Nuget package: Microsoft.Office.Core 15.0.0" - I think those charts were released in a later version of Excel.

Comment: Thanks, @BigBen Is there an updated package I could use?